# System wide push notifications

Tags: feature-request, notifications, notification-bar

I was thinking about this: the notification system of Stack Overflow is quite complete, in fact if my reputation changes or if someone answers questions, adds comments, etc., I can see it from the above status bar.

But many of this notifications will appear only when you reload the page, or change page, in general.

It could be a great improvement, I think, to make all these notifications appear through a push service. Something like what you see on Facebook or what you get on OS X using Grawl, I mean.

This way one could easily see when his/her reputation goes up or down, when new answers appear, when new comments appear, when a new badge is rewarded, and so on.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3):

I could see this as being nice for the Inbox.  But I see it more of an AJAX pull that fires every X minutes / seconds rather than a push.

On the flip side, this would generated a ton more requests that the sites will have to serve.  The ROI would need to be evaluated.

Comment: There are plenty of solutions for implementing a fast and reliable push service on the web. More or less they are quite always a sort of distorted pull service. It will improve making SO more "social" since it will be easier to follow what happens and what don't. I'd implement it for the inbox and everything else. Configurable, excludable, etc.